# How to split string before and after string and convert it into an expression?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console-application

There are some dynamic expressions and they are in string format. So how to separate string before and after the expression and perform some operations to each sub expression inside in it? I need the value of each sub expression separately and final decimal number. Not sure of how to separate the string before and after in the expression.

```
// the textfile contains 4'-8"x5/16"x20'-8 13/16 
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:arith.txt");

// 4*12+8+5/16+20*12+8+13/16
string path = text
  .Replace("'", "*12")
  .Replace("-", "+")
  .Replace("x", "+")
  .Replace(" ", "+")
  .Replace(@"""", "");

System.Console.WriteLine("The original string: '{0}'", text);
System.Console.WriteLine("The final string: '{0}'", path);

txtCalculate.Text = path;
```

---

> final expression I got after replacings is 
>   **4*12+8+5/16+20*12+8+13/16**
>
> But how to split values as below and get exact decimal values:
>
> a = (4*12+8)
>
> b = (5/16)
>
> c = (20*12+8+13/16)
>
> d = a + b + c;

Comment: I've executed your (*amended*: `string text = "4'-8\"x5/16\"x20'-8 13/16";`) code and I've got `"4*12+8+5/16+20*12+8+13/16"` as an outcome.

Comment: Why `a = 4*12+8` and `b = 5/16` and not `a = 4*12` when `b = 8+5/16`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you are right about the string text expression. I need to separate these values and show as different decimal values. Consider it as width, thick and length from the expression.

Comment: if `a`, `b`, `c` are in fact dimensions separated by `x` then it's quite natural first to `Split` them by `x` and then format out each dimension (with a help of chained `Replace`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest *first* `Split` and *only then* `Replace`:

```
  string text = "4'-8\"x5/16\"x20'-8 13/16"; 

  string[] items = text
    .Split('x')
    .Select(item => item
       .Replace("'", "*12")
       .Replace("-", "+")
       .Replace("x", "+")
       .Replace(" ", "+")
       .Replace(@"""", ""))
    .ToArray();
```

Test:

```
   Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items));
```

Outcome:

```
   4*12+8 
   5/16 
   20*12+8+13/16
```

If you want to format out the result  into a *formula* with `a`, `b`, `c`... (as you've put it in the question):

```
  string[] items = text
    .Split('x')
    .Select(item => item
       .Replace("'", "*12")
       .Replace("-", "+")
       .Replace("x", "+")
       .Replace(" ", "+")
       .Replace(@"""", ""))
    .Select((v, i) => $"{(char)('a' + i)} = ({v})")
    .ToArray();

  string formula = 
    string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items) + Environment.NewLine +
    $"{(char) ('a' + items.Length)} = " +
    string.Join(" + ", Enumerable.Range('a', items.Length).Select(c => $"{(char) (c)}"));

  Console.Write(formula);
```

Outcome:

```
a = (4*12+8)
b = (5/16)
c = (20*12+8+13/16)
d = a + b + c
```

Finally, you've mentioned

> **value** of each sub expression separately and final **decimal** number

and for simple formulae you can try [DataTable.Compute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string formula;

using (DataTable dt = new DataTable()) {
  string[] items = text
    .Split('x')
    .Select(item => item
       .Replace("'", "*12")
       .Replace("-", "+")
       .Replace("x", "+")
       .Replace(" ", "+")
       .Replace(@"""", ""))
    .ToArray();

  formula = 
    string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items
      .Select((v, i) => $"{(char) ('a' + i)} = ({v}) = {dt.Compute(v, null)}")) +
    Environment.NewLine +
    $"{(char) ('a' + items.Length)} = " +
    string.Join(" + ", Enumerable.Range('a', items.Length).Select(c => $"{(char) (c)}")) + 
    $" = {items.Sum(item => Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Compute(item, null)))}";
}

Console.Write(formula);
```

Outcome:

```
a = (4*12+8) = 56
b = (5/16) = 0.3125
c = (20*12+8+13/16) = 248.8125
d = a + b + c = 305.1250
```

Comment: how can i assign a, b, c  values to wt.textbox=a; het.textbox=b; lngt.textbox=c;

Comment: @madhu kumar: Something like this: `wt.textbox.Text = items[0];  het.textbox.Text = items[1]; lngt.textbox.Text = items[2];`; If you want to assign the final decimal value: `using(DataTable dt = new DataTable()) {wt.textbox.Text = dt.Compute(items[0], null).ToString(); ...}`

Comment: i have one problem with this. This is not processing empty textbox. This need to clear all the values for null value and all the items should become 0.

Comment: @madhu kumar: *null* (or *empty* as well?) case is a special one; so you have to add corresponding `if`, something like this: `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) {//TODO: put the desired outcome here} else {//Rest of the answer}`